# Is it possible to insert records based on record Types using DataLoader CLI Approach?

Tags: data-loader

> A. Can the DataLoader CLI load process create multiple records in
> SalesForce for the same object with different recordTypes?

Able to add records using DataLoader CLI Approach but Not sure how to add recordTypes?

> B. The DataLoader CLI load process while loading data into multiple
> objects during the load process should not create the duplicate? Is this
> possible using Data loader CLI approach?
>
> C. The Dataloader CLI load process must be able to send email alerts to
> notify SF Admin of the load process status – success, fail, or other
> statuses, etc.  Is this possible?

Please help me with the questions, New to dataLoader?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Dataloader Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the document for setting up DataLoader but got few questions which are custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A. Can the DataLoader CLI load process create multiple records in SalesForce for the same object with different recordTypes?

Yes, you can create record based on recordtype. You need to map csv column with RecordTypeId of Object.

> B. The DataLoader CLI load process while loading data into multiple objects during the load process should not create the duplicate? Is this possible using Data loader CLI approach?

Yes, you can create unique fields in Salesforce based on which duplicate insert can be restricted.

> C. The Dataloader CLI load process must be able to send email alerts to notify SF Admin of the load process status – success, fail, or other statuses, etc. Is this possible?

Refer this answer: [Send email afetercompletion of export in CLI dataloader](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BVa6IAG)